# Differentiate $\left(x^6-2x^2\right) \ln\left(x\right) \sin\left(x\right)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Differentiate

$$\left(x^6-2x^2\right)\ln\left(x\right)\sin\left(x\right)$$
with respect to $x$

**My work so far**

$\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{\tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[\left(x^6-2x^2\right)\ln\left(x\right)\sin\left(x\right)\right]}}$

$=\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-3}{\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-2}{\tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[x^6-2x^2\right]}}\cdot\ln\left(x\right)\sin\left(x\right)}}+\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-5}{\left(x^6-2x^2\right)\cdot\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-4}{\tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[\ln\left(x\right)\right]}}\cdot\sin\left(x\right)}}+\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-7}{\left(x^6-2x^2\right)\ln\left(x\right)\cdot\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-6}{\tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[\sin\left(x\right)\right]}}}}$

$=\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-8}{\left(\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-10}{\tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[x^6\right]}}-2\cdot\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-9}{\tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[x^2\right]}}\right)}}\ln\left(x\right)\sin\left(x\right)+\left(x^6-2x^2\right)\cdot\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-11}{\dfrac{1}{x}}}\sin\left(x\right)+\left(x^6-2x^2\right)\ln\left(x\right)\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-12}{\cos\left(x\right)}}$

$=\left(\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-13}{6}}\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-14}{x^5}}-2\cdot\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-15}{2}}\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-16}{x}}\right)\ln\left(x\right)\sin\left(x\right)+\dfrac{\left(x^6-2x^2\right)\sin\left(x\right)}{x}+\left(x^6-2x^2\right)\ln\left(x\right)\cos\left(x\right)$

$=\left(6x^5-4x\right)\ln\left(x\right)\sin\left(x\right)+\dfrac{\left(x^6-2x^2\right)\sin\left(x\right)}{x}+\left(x^6-2x^2\right)\cos\left(x\right)\ln\left(x\right)$

$=x\left(\left(\left(6x^4-4\right)\ln\left(x\right)+x^4-2\right)\sin\left(x\right)+\left(x^5-2x\right)\cos\left(x\right)\ln\left(x\right)\right)$

I've had great difficulty in solving this. Was my method correct?

Also, would there be any shortcuts in solving this, or is this method the best way of getting the solution?

Comment: You are correct. No shorter way.

Comment: Be glad you weren't asked to take the *second* derivative!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\left(x^6-2x^2\right)\ln x\sin x$. Then,

$$\ln f(x)=\ln(x^6-2x^2) +\ln (\ln x ) + \ln(\sin x)
$$

and

$$f’(x)=f(x)\left(\frac{6x^5-4x}{x^6-2x^2}+\frac{1}{x\ln x}+ \cot x\right)
$$

Comment: For the OP: this technique is called [logarithmic differentiation](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/logdiff.aspx).

Comment: Lovely method, thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

Your method is correct. If you have an derivative of a function that is the product of three other functions, it looks like this:

$$h(x)=f(x)\cdot g(x)\cdot y(x)$$
$$h'(x)=f'(x)\cdot g(x)\cdot y(x)+f(x)\cdot g'(x)\cdot y(x)+f(x)\cdot g(x)\cdot y'(x)$$

This derivative is just particularly algebraically intense, and at the end of the day I would leave it as you have on line 3.